# Create procedure for inserting the records, if exception, procedure needs start from exception line

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, procedure

I need to write the procedure for inserting the records in to multiple tables, for example I have 3 table,

```
CREATE TABLE SOURCE 
( 
SORT_CODE NUMBER, 
FLAG CHAR(1) 
); 

INSERT INTO SOURCE VALUES(605096,5); 
INSERT INTO SOURCE VALUES(605097,5); 
INSERT INTO SOURCE VALUES(605098,5); 
INSERT INTO SOURCE VALUES(605099,5); 
INSERT INTO SOURCE VALUES(605100,5); 
INSERT INTO SOURCE VALUES(605101,6); 
INSERT INTO SOURCE VALUES(605102,6); 
INSERT INTO SOURCE VALUES(605103,6); 
INSERT INTO SOURCE VALUES(605104,6); 
INSERT INTO SOURCE VALUES(605105,6); 

SQL> SELECT * FROM SOURCE; 

SORT_CODE F 
---------- - 
605096 5 
605097 5 
605098 5 
605099 5 
605100 5 
605101 6 
605102 6 
605103 6 
605104 6 
605105 6 

10 rows selected. 

CREATE TABLE TARGET 
( 
SORT_CODE NUMBER, 
TARGET_SORT_CODE NUMBER 
); 

Table created.
```

INSERT 5 VALUES

```
INSERT INTO TARGET VALUES(605101,189873); 
INSERT INTO TARGET VALUES(605102,189874); 
INSERT INTO TARGET VALUES(605103,189875); 
INSERT INTO TARGET VALUES(605104,189876); 
INSERT INTO TARGET VALUES(605105,''); 


SELECT * FROM TARGET; 

SORT_CODE TARGET_SORT_CODE 
---------- ---------------- 
605101 189873 
605102 189874 
605103 189875 
605104 189876 
605105 

CREATE TABLE NEWID 
( 
SORT_CODE NUMBER, 
ID_SCODE NUMBER 
); 

Table created.
```

INSERT 2 VALUES

```
INSERT INTO TARGET VALUES(605103,189875); 
INSERT INTO TARGET VALUES(605104,189876); 

SELECT * FROM NEWID; 

SORT_CODE ID_SCODE 
---------- ---------------- 
605103 189875 
605104 189876
```

Creating intermediate tables with existing table's structure.

```
CREATE TABLE SOURCE_TEMP AS (SELECT * FROM SOURCE WHERE 1=2); 
CREATE TABLE TARGET_TEMP AS (SELECT * FROM TARGET WHERE 1=2); 
CREATE TABLE NEWID_TEMP AS (SELECT * FROM NEWID WHERE 1=2);
```

My Procedure for inserting the records

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insert_sql 
is 
BEGIN 

DELETE FROM SOURCE_TEMP; 
INSERT INTO SOURCE_TEMP SELECT * FROM SOURCE; --insert query 1 

DELETE FROM TARGET_TEMP; 
INSERT INTO TARGET_TEMP SELECT * FROM TARGET; --insert query 2 
--due to some network issue or table error this procedure GOT EXEPCTION here and above insert query 2(TARGET_TEMP) and below --insert query 3(NEWID_TEMP) is not inserted the values or not executed procedure is came out from this line. 

DELETE FROM NEWID_TEMP; 
INSERT INTO NEWID_TEMP SELECT * FROM NEWID; --insert query 3 

EXCEPTION 
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ERROR'); 
END;
```

Point 1: The above procedure is executed only one insert query 1 SOURCE_TEMP is got the values. 
Point 1: TARGET_TEMP and NEWID_TEMP is not inserted the values or not execute.

My question: can I re-execute this procedure with starting point of '--insert query 2' line?

because I am inserting the 100 tables records in new tables, if 50 tables are inserted the values during this time if I am getting any error in the proc execution, remaining 50 tables needs to insert the values, for I don't wish to delete the previous 50 tables inserted the values it will be the time consuming activity. Any save point or boolean concepts is there for this type of issue in ORACLE (which is available in java and unix).  if yes how to use this function?

Comment: Please modify your question's title to make it the proper casing (i.e. turn off your caps lock).

Comment: Stop SHOUTING - We are not deaf

Comment: "*Any save point or boolean concepts is there for this type of issue in ORACLE*"  - yes there is. Surprisingly the corresponding command is called `savepoint`: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10001.htm#SQLRF01701

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insert_sql 
is
 v_new_rec_count int:=0; 
BEGIN 
select count(*) 
into v_new_rec_count 
from (
select * FROM SOURCE
minus
select * FROM SOURCE_TEMP
) ;
If v_new_rec_count >0 then
INSERT INTO SOURCE_TEMP SELECT * FROM SOURCE; --insert query 1 
Commit;--permanently save the records in table and it wont be rolledback after -             --      any subsequent failure.
v_new_rec_count  :=0;
end if;


select count(*) 
into v_new_rec_count 
from (
select * FROM TARGET
minus
select * FROM TARGET_TEMP
) ;
If v_new_rec_count >0 then
INSERT INTO TARGET_TEMP SELECT * FROM TARGET; --insert query 2 
Commit;--permanently save the records in table and it wont be rolledback after -             --      any subsequent failure.
v_new_rec_count  :=0;
end if;


select count(*) 
into v_new_rec_count 
from (
select * FROM NEWID
minus
select * FROM NEWID_TEMP
) ;
If v_new_rec_count >0 then
INSERT INTO NEWID_TEMP SELECT * FROM NEWID; --insert query 2 
Commit;--permanently save the records in table and it wont be rolledback after -             --      any subsequent failure.
v_new_rec_count  :=0;
end if;

EXCEPTION 
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ERROR'); 
END;
```

Comment: Thanks Prashant Mishra Thanks for Your Help, I created the Proc, ur procedure is good and only it is not satisfy whn some error is occured, the procedure should run on the next statement from the error line

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to All ur support

I created the Proc, Finally I got PLSQL-PROCEDURE to execute my concepts.

```
create TABLE FLAG 
( 
FLAG VARCHAR2(6) 
); 

INSERT INTO FLAG VALUES('PASS01');
```

Answer (score 0):

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insert_sql

IS

x int;

FLG FLAG.FLAG%type;

BEGIN

dbms_output.enable;

SELECT FLAG INTO FLG FROM FLAG;

if FLG='PASS01' then

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('PASS01');

DELETE FROM SOURCE_TEMP;

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('SOURCE_TEMP-DELETED');

INSERT INTO SOURCE_TEMP SELECT * FROM SOURCE;

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('SOURCE_TEMP-INSERTED');

UPDATE FLAG SET FLAG='PASS02';

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('PASS02-updated');

SELECT FLAG INTO FLG FROM FLAG;

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('PASS02-SELECT');

COMMIT;

end if;

if FLG='PASS02' then

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('PASS02');

DELETE FROM TARGET_TEMP;

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('TARGET_TEMP-DELETED');

INSERT INTO TARGET_TEMP SELECT * FROM TARGET;

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('TARGET_TEMP-INSERTEDD');

UPDATE FLAG SET FLAG='PASS03';

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('PASS03-updated');

SELECT FLAG INTO FLG FROM FLAG;

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('PASS03-FLG');

COMMIT;

end if;

--x :=1/0;

if FLG='PASS03' then

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('PASS03');

DELETE FROM NEWID_TEMP;

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('NEWID_TEMP-DELETED');

INSERT INTO NEWID_TEMP SELECT * FROM NEWID;

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('NEWID_TEMP-INSERTEDD');

UPDATE FLAG SET FLAG='PASS01';

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('PASS01-updated');

SELECT FLAG INTO FLG FROM FLAG;

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('PASS01-FLG');

COMMIT;

end if;

EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('NO_DATA_FOUND!');

WHEN OTHERS THEN DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error Message: !'|| SQLERRM ||' Sql Code: ' || SQLCODE);

END;

Answer (score 0):

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insert_sql 
is
 v_new_rec_count int:=0; 
 CURSOR cur_src
 IS
 SELECT * FROM SOURCE ;
 TYPE cur_src_typ IS TABLE OF cur_src%ROWTYPE;
  cur_src_tbl cur_src_typ;

 CURSOR cur_newid
 IS
 SELECT * FROM newid ;
 TYPE cur_newid_typ IS TABLE OF cur_src%ROWTYPE;
 cur_newid_tbl cur_newid_typ;

 CURSOR cur_target
 IS
 SELECT * FROM target ;
 TYPE cur_target_typ IS TABLE OF cur_src%ROWTYPE;
 cur_target_tbl cur_target_typ;

BEGIN 
cur_src_tbl :=cur_src_tbl();
cur_newid_tbl :=cur_newid_tbl();
cur_target_tbl :=cur_target_tbl();


OPEN cur_src;
LOOP
FETCH cur_src BULK COLLECT INTO cur_src_tbl LIMIT 500;
EXIT WHEN cur_src_tbl.count =0;
FOR i IN cur_src LOOP
 BEGIN
 INSERT INTO SOURCE_TEMP VALUES(cur_src(i).sort_code,cur_src(i).flag);
 COMMIT;
 EXCEPTION 
 WHEN OTHERS THEN NULL;
 END;
 CLOSE cur_src;

OPEN cur_target;
LOOP
FETCH cur_target BULK COLLECT INTO cur_target_tbl LIMIT 500;
EXIT WHEN cur_target.count =0;
FOR i IN cur_target_tbl LOOP
 BEGIN
 INSERT INTO target_temp VALUES(cur_target_tbl(i).sort_code,cur_target_tbl(i).target_sort_code);
 COMMIT;
 EXCEPTION 
 WHEN OTHERS THEN NULL;
 END;
 CLOSE cur_newid;

 OPEN cur_newid;
LOOP
FETCH cur_newid BULK COLLECT INTO cur_newid_tbl LIMIT 500;
EXIT WHEN cur_newid_tbl.count =0;
FOR i IN cur_newid_tbl LOOP
 BEGIN
 INSERT INTO newid_TEMP VALUES(cur_newid_tbl(i).sort_code,cur_newid_tbl(i).flag);
 COMMIT;
 EXCEPTION 
 WHEN OTHERS THEN NULL;
 END;
 CLOSE cur_newid;

END;
```